# Combine several functions with restrictions , keeping only one equation

Tags: functions

How do I combine these two functions that both have restrictions **into a single equation**?
$$f(x)=|x|\times\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
and
$$g(x)=-|x|\times\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Just see their domains, you can easily define a piecewise function.

Comment: I am looking for a equation that combines both of them but in a single equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?
$$h(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{|x^2-1|}\cdot|x|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{|x^2-1|}}{\sqrt{|x^2-1|}}$$

If $x^2-1\gt 0$, then
$$h(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2-1}\cdot|x|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=f(x).$$
Note that $f(x)$ is defined only when $x^2-1\gt 0$.

If $x^2-1\lt 0$, then
$$h(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{-(x^2-1)}\cdot|x|\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=g(x).$$
Note that $g(x)$ is defined only when $x^2-1\lt 0$.

Added : As a user Mann points out, 
$$\frac{x^2-1}{|x^2-1|}\cdot|x|$$
should work.

Comment: I think only $\frac{x^2-1}{|x^2-1|}*|x|$ does the work.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mrtsvvoppq

Comment: @Mann: Ah, you mean that I don't need $\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ part. I think you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Is there a way to combine 4+ different functions, also in this fashion?

Comment: @IonLee: Well, it depends. Can you give a concrete example? (I think if you have another question, it's better for you to ask it as a new question :)

Comment: Probably best to answer another question. I'll post the new question in the comments when I do.

Answer (score 0):

What about $$h(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x) & \textrm{for }|x|<1 \\
0 & \textrm{for }|x|=1 \\
f(x) & \textrm{for }|x|>1\\
\end{cases}$$
assuming you want the function to be zero if $x=\pm 1$. (If you don't want that, omit the second case.)